# Preserving cross domain GA on mobile redirect, how to do this properly?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I have a site, let's say `test.com`. This incorporates Google Tag Manager. I have a console for booking, this goes to a different domain. So the form's action is say, `bookings.anotherdomain.com`.

When the form is submitted, the URL becomes `bookings.anotherdomain.com/?_ga=TOKEN`. From what I understand, `_ga` is the new param for all google tracking, all the utm params are stored for it in google's database.

On `bookings.anotherdomain.com`, for the moment this site is not fully responsive and has a "sniffer" script that redirects to `mobile.yetanotherdomain.com`. **Yes, that's 3 different domains.**

The problem is during the redirect from `bookings.anotherdomain.com` to `mobile.yetanotherdomain.com`, no GA params are passed. This redirect happens via server side.

I'm wondering if the proper procedure would be to pass the `_ga` variable?

```
$ga = '?_ga=' . htmlspecialchars( $_REQUEST['_ga'] );
header('Location: mobile.yetanotherdomain.com/' . $ga );
exit;
```

Would this be the right way of sending the GA params? I can't use JS for this as I want to keep it a server-side redirect, so that eliminates any GA JS script calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes, forward that URL parameter if you can.

It sounds like you're using the analytics.js [linker plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink), which is designed to do cross-domain tracking. Analytics.js keeps track of a particular user on a domain by storing a client ID value in a cookie. So, in order for analytics.js to track a particular user when she leaves domain A and goes to domain B, that client ID must be passed somehow. That's what the `_ga=TOKEN` URL parameter is -- the client ID.

In order for the destination domain to know to check for that `_ga` URL param, you have to tell your tracking code to expect it. The developer guide I linked to above should explain how to do that.

This site also has some good information on cross-domain tracking:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342

I hope that helps; let me know if you want more details.